# Can we have two Iterators of pyfirmata inside a same program?

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I am using pyfirmata library of python and I am new to it.
So I am using one Arduino UNO and one Arduino Mega in a same program.I want to have one Iterator for each.Is it possible?
If yes, how?

I have tried using-

```
board = Arduino
it = util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

boardMega = ArduinoMega
itMega = util.Iterator(boardMega)
itMega.start()
```

But only the first works, the second one does not.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get a error message and if yes what does it say?

Comment: @Teekeks basically I am using that in a try-exception block. So the board.analog[Pin].read() returns none.

Comment: Can you please do your except block like this and add what it prints to your question?
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)

Comment: @Teekeks,lets forget about except block. My question now is when i run the program all the boardMega.analog/digital[Pin].read() returns None. I want to know why and how to correct that